# Как выжать максимум информации из gdb при анализе стека вызовов?

Tags: freebsd, c, unix, отладка, gdb

Добрый день!
Не получается выяснить точное место падения программы, трассировка при падении выводит такой вот стек вызовов :

> Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
> 0x380410bd in ??
> () (gdb) bt
> 0  0x380410bd in ?? ()
> 1  0x006b5030 in ?? ()
> 2  0xbebf42a8 in ?? ()
> 3  0xbebf42a8 in ?? ()
> 4  0x00000014 in ?? ()
> 5  0xbebf4570 in ?? ()
> 6  0x000f988c in EC_toByte () from /usr/local/lib/libfcrypt.so.3
> 7  0x0804b44c in main (argc=3, argv=0xbebfec74) at test.c:462

Библиотека *libfcrypt* доступна только в бинарнике, функция *EC_toByte()* явным образом в коде программы не вызывается, не могу понять как вообще туда попала. Попытки прицепиться к кадрам стека ни к чему не привели - "No source file for address 0x380410bd".  Есть ли способ более точно отследить последовательность вызовов в gdb или что-то еще, что поможет понять, где именно валится программа?

**Добавлено.**

```
 while(1) {
// подготовка наборов дескрипторов для вызова select
FD_ZERO(&rd_set);
FD_ZERO(&wr_set);

FD_SET(p_cfg->fd_usock,&rd_set);
FD_SET(p_cfg->fd_isock,&rd_set);
md = shd_selfd(NULL);

shd_fdset_print(&rd_set,&wr_set,(SHD_PTHR *)NULL); 
#ifdef DEBUG
 DPRT(DPRT_COMMON,"max descriptor - %d",md);
#endif
res = select(md,&rd_set,NULL,NULL,&sel_tout);
```

**Добавлено.**
Появилась еще одна настораживающая деталь - в момент падения выполняется 3 потока, в одном из потоков после функции блокирования мьютекса на вершине стека красуются :

```
Thread 2 (Thread 100110):
#0  0x004117d3 in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x0040ff98 in pthread_mutex_getprioceiling () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0041000a in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libthr.so.3
```

в данной векте потока вызова функции *pthread_kill()* нет и в помине, может кто-то знает, в каких случаях она может вызваться системой? Я предполагаю, что это какой-то конфликт при захвате мьютекса, может подобное вызвать порчу стека?

Comment: А это что?
> 7 0x0804b44c in main (argc=3, argv=0xbebfec74) at test.c:462
Честно говоря, у меня подозрение, что где-то в программе (Вашей?) переполнение буфера.

Comment: эта строчка - вызов select(), к данной библиотеке он никак не может обращаться

Comment: Может если, на входе select мусорные данные. Например, какая-нибудь не 0-terminated строка. Не?

Comment: на входе select() - вполне валидные дескрипторы прослушиваемых сокетов - всего 2 штуки

Comment: Код давайте вокруг test.c:462

Comment: Программа постоянно (или когда) валиться в select() ? 

Как она с разными таймаутами (например с 0 (не NULL)) ?

Можно ли ее потестировать руками (например ncat-ом, если правильно понял Вы с сокетами работаете)

Comment: Еще раз повторю, что идет разрушение стека. <a href=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616813/getting-sigill-when-trying-to-execute-buffer-overflow-attack>Пример есть не один</a>. Тогда нужен полный код. Если заинтересованы в решение проблемы - свяжитесь со мной, посмотрим. Контакты есть в профиле.

Comment: @avp, валится в select() постоянно, но! пока только при запуске под valgrind. при обычном запуске не валилась, но это не показатель,т.к. программа многопоточная.  Тестирую вручную своим тестовым клиентом.
@gecube, я разумеется заинтересована, и Вы вероятно правы насчет разрушения стека, просто пока я не могу локализовать баг, однако я хотела бы все таки разобраться в своих багах сама, поэтому вопрос насчет дополнительных опций gdb, которые могли бы помочь в поиске - в силе. Например есть адрес, по которому все свалилось. Можно ли отследить, когда произошла запись данных по этому адресу?

Comment: Про возможность отследить время даже не слышал. 

Почему бы не сделать точку останова в gdb на этот select() и не посмотреть все перед его вызовом ?

Comment: @margosh, не знаю, где в FreeBSD (у меня в linux /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/select.h) посмотрите typedef для fd_set и определение _FD_SET (у меня в /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/select.h).

Это очевидное место для порчи памяти (у меня никаких проверок нет). Т.е. прежде всего отследите все свои FD_SET, FD_CLR и т.п. на предмет правильности номера дескриптора и адреса битового вектора.

И вообще (м.б. конечно, что так и должно быть) меня смущает адрес 0x00000014 в посмертном стеке.

--

Кстати, **самый первый** вызов slect() тоже валится ?

Comment: Если у Вас разрешено прерывание (запрещен рестарт) системных вызовов при получении сигнала, то

rc = select(...)  

rc == -1 и errno == EINTR проверяете корректно ? (Кстати, это относится ко всем системным вызовам (в т.ч. в функциях libc) во **всех потоках**)

Обработка SIGCHLD может проходить в *любом* потоке (где не замаскирован SIGCHLD).

Comment: Нет, select() валится всегда после того, как программа получила SIGCHLD, при этом в его обработчике криминала нет - единственное, что он делает - пишет сиамвол в pipe. В потоке, который этот канал читает, так же дескрипторы, которые проверяются в данном selecte, не затрагиваются никак. Единственное, что происходит с данными дескрипторами - их закрытие при завершении работы, но к SIGCHLD это никакого отношения не имеет. 

При rc < 0 и errno == EINTR возвращаюсь в начало цикла, и перезапускаю select() во всех потоках. SIGCHLD замаскирован во всех потоках, кроме основного